# How to navigate to adb exe using command prompt in windows 7

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to familiarise myself with using adb from the command prompt.
My adb.exe is installed at:
C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

I have tried starting off by typing in cd:C\ to take me to the C drive
Then I have typed in the path quoted above, sometimes putting Program Files(x86) in quote marks,
other times inserting % in between Program and Files.
But always I get the same answer - "The system cannot find the path specified".
Even when I type the path and then put in “adb devices” I get nothing.
I have tried inserting each of the following in the path in system variables as follows:
;C:\"Program Files(x86)"\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\
C:\"Program Files(x86)"\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\
;C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
And then typing “adb devices”.
The message is the same – “adb is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch command.

Comment: what is your android sdk's folder name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call adb directly from the directory you are currently in: 
 `"C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe"` (With quotes!) 
 You can also navigate to the `platform-tools` directory and then call `adb.exe`, use `cd ..` to go to a directory level up, you can hit `TAB` to let windows list the appropriate directories, this works also if one or more characters are entered.

Btw, just added "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools" to my `PATH` and it works just fine! Separate the entires with a semicolon.

Comment: I've tried that iDroid and it says system cannot find the path specified

Comment: I've added that to my path too but it says "adb is not recognised.."

Comment: Hmmm... Are you sure there are no problems with your sdk installation and the adb.exe is actually existing under the path mentioned above? Try to navigate to the directory using windows explorer and drag & drop the adb.exe into an opened cmd-window.

Comment: When I drag and drop it like you said it obviously recognises it because I get a window full of information. My command line then returns to C:\Users\Steve> and my problem is that I am once again stuck in the same place I started from. Unable to run any commands.

Comment: I've just noticed that if I do as you say - drag from the window - I can attach my instructions. e.g. "devices" and it works. So I will use it that way. Your advice has been very helpful. I cannot understand why I cannot just type in the same path to get it to work. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

for using a 64 bit os try going step by step,
type in command prompt

> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)"

you will enter C:\Program Files (x86)directory 
then type

> cd Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 0):

It's the **spaces that are messing people up**. Windows users need to remember one important thing when dealing with command lines: **do not install the utilities to folders where there's a space in the folder name** - it will save you a lot of hassle which sometimes can't even be solved by using quotes.

For example, I've installed the Android SDK to `C:\Android\android-sdk-windows`

To open a command prompt, I have a shortcut to ("target") `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
And the "Start in" path is `C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools`

now all I do is double-click the shortcut and I can dive right in to ADB